# Uppercase second half of a string

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program in Python that will uppercase the second half of a given string, according to it's length.

I was looking for a more elegant solution without using any loops of functions.

Ideas?

```
string = input('please enter a string')

length = len(string) // 2

first_half_string = string[0:length]

second_half_string = string[length::]

print(first_half_string + second_half_string.upper())
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code (except fixing `string[length::]` to `string[length:]`)?

Comment: nothing, it works. was hoping for some alternative approach...

Comment: It's not immediately clear what the issue is. As is, it already isn't using any loops.

Answer (score 2):

Without iterating over the string, slicing (what you did) is probably the best approach already. You could trim the code down to one line even:

```
print(string[0:len(string)//2] + string[len(string)//2:].upper())
```